# Tableau - How to display last # of days on a line chart

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have a tableau line chart report where the X axis is the Call Date, I'm trying to display dynamically the last 14 days, but unable to do it in tableau.  In T-SQL I can easily do `WHERE CallDate between CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-14,101) and CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-1,101)`

[image]

For example, the line chart below, I want to display Sept 1 to 14 then when Sept 15 comes Sept 1 will drop from the line chart view so on and so forth.
I tried to use the Top N, but it is not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

You can create a calculated field to select the last 14 days, and then apply it as the filter in your chart.

Calculated Field:

```
[Date] > DATEADD('day', -14, TODAY()) AND [Date]<= TODAY()
```

If you want the days to be dynamic and can be selected by user, you can create a parameter and use it in the calculated field.

```
[Date] > DATEADD('day', -[Days], TODAY()) AND [Date]<= TODAY()
```

The `[Days]` here is the name of parameter.

[image]

Comment: FYI, you can simplify this a bit by just keeping the condition (i.e. the part of the calculated field after “IF” and before “THEN”). Then you’ll have a Boolean valued field instea of a string. Booleans are first class citizens.

Comment: I would suggest taking your idea one step further. Instead of hard coding the 14 days, make that value a parameter so that the end-user has total control over the time period that gets displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the input @AlexBlakemore, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input @SamM, I have updated my answer.

Comment: The 14 days is not going to be a parameter. I'm trying to showcase a line chart on Month to Date and 14 days worth of data. There will be no user interaction in selecting this parameter. It is a good idea but not with my audience. Thanks Larry great code sharing.. :)

Comment: Code works perfect. Thanks. I was able to display the last 14 mos in a line chart using (DATEPART('year', [Call Date])*100 + DATEPART('month', [Call Date])) code, but I'm unable to tweak the code to display the month abbreviation + year (ex. Sep 2018). can you assist? thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Drag your "Call Date" to Filters card and select "Relative Dates" then select "Last 14 days" and hit OK. This will make the filter dynamic.